# "What can I be of help"

Tags: meaning

In a forum of a website, I read the following sentences (the writer is referring to a session in a conference):

> Makes lots of sense. Not sure what can I be of help (and I already have
>   two sessions on the official schedule), but would be happy to be of
>   help.

Is it correct to say *what can I be of help*?
Is it commonly used? Is it used in restricted groups?

Comment: I would diagnose 'typo' of 'what' where 'that' was intended.  It is not *correct*, but in a forum, you cannot expect every message to be perfectly grammatically correct, and should allow for lax usage.  (This forum is something of an exception; the people here are concerned about correct usage, so most content can be scrutinized for accuracy.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sentences contains some quirks, and a lot of references are omitted.

*Sense* is not quantifiable, so the variation *a lot of sense* feels more natural and is more commonly used than *lots of sense*.

The expression isn't *what can I be of help* but rather *what I can do to help* or *how I can be of help*.

I fleshed out the sentences so that they read like written language:

> That makes a lot of sense. I'm not sure what I can do to be of help (and I already have two sessions on the official schedule), but I would be happy to be of help.

Comment: Do you mean that the answer to my last two questions is then "no"?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Sorry if I was unclear. That is correct, the answer is no; the expression is wrong.

Comment: @Guffa: There is no need to be sorry. I wanted to be sure that what you meant was what I understood. I was not sure you noticed those "subquestions", and you simply forgot to answer to those.

Comment: "lots of sense" sounds fine to my ears.  Maybe not grammatical, but who cares ;-).  Other than that, I agree.

Comment: _lots of_ is reported from the NOAD as variant for _a lot of_; both the phrases are marked as informal, in sentences like _she had lots of fun_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes, there is no strict difference between them, and both are informal. There seems to be a difference in which words they are commonly used with, though. A quick google comparison shows 50 times more hits for "a lot of sense" than "lost of sense", so that combination seems to be much more commonly used.

Answer (score 6):

Better to say *How can I be of help?* or *What can I help with?* (yes I know there is a preposition at the end), or even more simply *How can I help?*

Comment: Just to reinforce Henry's point: "Not sure what I can be of help" sounds quite awkward, and it is something to be avoided.

Comment: What is your answer to my last three "sub-questions"?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: No, no and I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

or *Not sure what I can do to be of help*. 
The original reads as though the writer was in a hurry, and so employed faulty grammar.

Answer (score 1):

I read *what can I be of help* as a possible contraction of *in what way can I be of help*. Regardless of what the writer means, however, the construction *can I* is incongruous here, as is it usually used in the interrogative sense. Thus, it should be *I can*.

Summary of possible options for this context:

> - [In] what [way] I can be of help
> - how I can be of help
> - when I can be of help *(the writer points to scheduling obligations)*