# "to be (of)" versus "to have" with properties of objects

Tags: word-choice

Regarding properties of objects, say, length or mass, I'm confident that "to have" will usually work but am unsure about "to be" or "to be of".  Consider the following examples:

(a) The vectors must **have** the same length.
(b) The vectors must **be** the same length.
(c) The vectors must **be of** the same length.

and

(d) The aggregate must **have** a density greater than 1800 kg/m³.
(e) The aggregate must **be** a density greater than 1800 kg/m³.
(f) The aggregate must **be of** a density greater than 1800 kg/m³.

(a) and (d) sound best to me, but I'm unclear whether the others are acceptable alternatives.
I looked at Ngrams for the three formulations using length, weight, mass, and density with inconsistent results.

- be mass > have mass > be of mass
- be density ≈ have density > be of density
- have weight > be weight > be of weight (though be of was more common
  before 1940)
- have length > be length, be of length

Comment: _Be density_ and _be mass_ sound wrong. _Of_ is good with both of them.  Vectors are abstract, hence their properties can _be_; but density and mass (and many other properties) are physical, not abstract, so they can be _had_ by physical objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning and usage of "be of"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47382/meaning-and-usage-of-be-of)

Comment: (b) The vectors must be the same length. New (g) The aggregate density must be greater than 1800 kg/m³. Presumably 'aggregate' here is synonymous with 'gravel'.

Comment: ... or (h) The density of the aggregate must be greater than 1800 kg/m³.

Comment: I agree that "to be" works well when the sentences are restructured as suggested: the (property) of the (object) is ...  But I was asking how the property relates to the object.  That is, the object {is, is of, has} property ... The 2x4 {is, is of, has} length 8 feet.

Comment: @PeterShor, Sorry, but that thread is of little comfort or use.   I see that the answer in the other thread got +30 rating, but isn't it a cop-out to say everything is idiomatic?

Comment: @JohnLawler,  the distinction between abstract and physical objects is intriguing but not convincing.  Is it that abstract nouns possess some purity that physical objects lack?  A vector in general is abstract, but (4,3,2,1) is a specific vector of length four.  So, (4, 3, 2, 1) {is, is of, has} length four?

Comment: No, it's merely that abstract attributes don't exist and therefore have no physical properties. Things that do exist are subject to physical laws and language is designed to deal with those (at least in a 1-G field at STP for humans). Abstract concepts are just names in systems of nodes (more abstractions) and follow their own logic, but anything semantic is metaphoric.